# Emberjs route model with view

Tags: ember.js

My app has a page where I'm using the view to display the data from other template with my view like this :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="enquiry">
        [...] // some other information display before
    {{view App.EnquirySelectedVehicleView}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="selectedVehicle">
    // Here is my content
</script>
```

My map looks like this :

```
this.resource('enquiry', { path: '/enquiry/:enquiry_id'}, function() {
    this.route('selectedVehicle');
});
```

After reading the doc I just did this in my view :

```
App.EnquirySelectedVehicleView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'selectedVehicle'
});
```

So far so good, its showing the text from my template. But I need to return data from an ajax call in this template (selectedVehicle) automatically, like its fetching the data when you are on /enquiry/1/.

I've done this in my router :

```
App.EnquirySelectedVehicle = Ember.Object.extend({});

App.EnquirySelectedVehicleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        console.log('DEBUG: SelectedVehicle Model');
        App.SelectedVehicle.vehicleStock(this)
    }
});

App.EnquirySelectedVehicle.reopenClass({
    vehicleStock: function(that) {
        console.log('DEBUG: Fetch vehicle stock');
        // Here come the ajax call
    }
});
```

But my issue is that route is never call.. How can I return some value from my selectedVehicleRoute when I'm on the /enquiry/1 page in a view template ? (not sure if I ask it correctly)

Thanks for the help !

[edit]

@Fanta : I think I begin to understand how I can do that :

```
App.EnquiryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    beforeModel: function(transition) {
        this.controllerFor('login').send('isSession', transition);
    },
    model: function(param) {
        var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var modelData = {enquiry: {}, vehicleStock: {}};
            Ember.$
            .get(host + '/enquiry/' + param['enquiry_id'], function(data) {
                console.log('DEBUG: Enquriry GET OK id = ' + param['enquiry_id']);
                modelData.enquiry = data.enquiry;
                Ember.$.get(host + '/vehiclestock/' + data.enquiry.VehicleStockId, function(data) {
                    console.log('DEBUG: VehicleStock GET OK id = ' + data.enquiry.VehicleStockId)
                    console.log(data);
                    modelData.vehicleStock = data.vehicleStock;
                    resolve(modelData);
                });
            });
        });
        return promise;
    }
});
```

It seems to work, now I have to figure it out how to display my Object :) but thank you for your help, that actually make me resolve it by a different way !

Comment: check the docs http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/ if you check, you'll see that your route should be something like App.EnquirySelectedVehicleRoute

Comment: I've edited the topic to put this modification but its still the same, nothing is triggering the router..

Comment: create a fiddle with your code, that would be easier for us to help.

Comment: I never managed to make a fiddle working with ember... http://jsfiddle.net/tJK8V/1/ I don't know if this can help, sorry...

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, just go to https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md and you'll see two links, one to JSFiddle and one to a JSBin with the basic setup.

Are you sure the route is not being called ? I created a Fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/817/ if you check the JS console, you'll see in the log:

```
DEBUG: SelectedVehicle Model
DEBUG: Fetch vehicle stock
```

Comment: I am 100% sure that my route isn't call. But in your Fiddle you're doing a redirect to enquiry.selectedVehicle. But I never reach my URL because I'm always on enquiry/id. I want to display data from this template in my enquiry, but I need to fetch some data from my server.

Comment: ok, so, use the fiddle I gave you, and put more of your code, just to see how you're doing things.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/818/ I've put most of my code. To explain it quickly, I have a list of enquiries and I use YUI to display it. I catch the click event with didInsertElement to trigger my controller and redirect me to the correct enquiry at /enquiry/id. And on my page enquiry/id I want to display some information coming from different ajax call but in one page. Thats why I wanted to use the view to display it.

Comment: the Fiddle is complaining about this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'reopenClass' of undefined. Btw, if you will use Ember data in your Fiddle, you need to add http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-data-latest.js to your external resources in the Fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/819/ My bad forgot to put the object create before. But you will not be able to do much with this code since its interacting a lot with my server..

Comment: Ok, I was trying to set up the fiddle with some test data, because the code that you put there doesn't work. Id does not do anything. But I suddenly saw what you're trying to say. So, you are expecting that by calling "view App.EnquirySelectedVehicleView" the App.EnquirySelectedVehicle gets fired ? that's not possible.

Comment: Yeah that what I was trying to do.. Is there is a way to do almost the same thing but around ? :/

Comment: what do you want to do with that code ? to show a list of vehicles in stock for that enquiry ? if that's what you want, then, why don't you just create a relationship between the enquiry and the vehicles in stock ? and loop through them ? that's if your using Ember data, if you are not, then... create a method somewhere, maybe in the 'enquiry' model, which is going to retrieve the 'vehicles' form an Ajax call, and return a promise, that way, when the promise is resolved, the template will be populated.

Comment: But in the Enquiry I already retrieve some information from enquiry request, for the vehicle I need to do a /vehicleStock for that and I can't do both in the same time while I can return jsut one ? I could also use Ember-Data but my server isn't optimise for this..

Comment: I mean, just move the vehicleStock method to your Enquiry model, and loop through the results, thats what you want, don't you ?